# Document library properties in sharepoint other than default like Title, Description

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries, sharepoint-2013

Is it possible to add additional properties to a document library in SharePoint using OOTB or Customization?
By default Document library has properties like Title, Description.
I need to add an other custom property in a library level which i can use it for further purpose.

Appreciate your inputs..

Thanks,
Gnanasekhar K

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have metadata for folders/Library, You can look in to "Document Sets"(OOTB)
You can create columns and even run workflows on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom columns to document library. Navigate to document library settings and click on add new column. Or Alternatively click on Create Column option in the ribbon.

Choose the column display name, data type and other properties like default values, choice options etc. (depending upon the type of column you intend to create) and click on OK button.

You would be able to see the column in the default list view. You will also be able to capture the column's value for each document (after you upload it) via Edit properties form.

Refer [this][1] article for more details

For storing metadata for document library, you can use property bags. Property bags can be associated with

- farm
- web application
- site collection
- site
- list/library

You can do this using

- Powershell script
- [CSOM code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171637/provision-property-bag-for-document-library-declaratively-via-sandbox)
- [JSOM code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171637/provision-property-bag-for-document-library-declaratively-via-sandbox)

Comment: Hi Vineet, Thanks for your reply, i am looking for library properties, not document properties, as you mentioned create column will give properties at document level not library level.

Comment: @user2115269: At document library level, you can use property bags for storing the values. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: There are also some codeplex utilities to manage those properties:

 - SharePoint Property Bag Settings 2013: https://pbs2013.codeplex.com
 - SharePoint Property Bag Settings 2010: https://pbs2010.codeplex.com
 - SharePoint 2010 Dynamic Settings: http://sp2010dynsettings.codeplex.com
 - SharePoint Property Bag Settings 2007: http://pbs2007.codeplex.com

Comment: We can use Property bag information programmatically, but i want to display that information like the default Title, Description.
In my case i want to store some URL information for each document library like Title, Description.